# How can I fix the way javascript runs and consolidate the way the page loads in all types of tabs

Tags: javascript, html, ip

I want to be able to get an alert with my ip address when I click the button but something strange is happening:
In a normal tab: The site loads and nothing happens when I click the button.
In a private tab: The alert comes and once you press ok the button loads and on pressing nothing happens. The javascript function ran even though I didn't use

How can I fix this? 
Thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    function getIP(json) {
      alert(json.ip);
    }
  </script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="getIP()">CLICK ME</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getIP` is being called when the ipify.org script finishes loading. If you want to only display that ip when the button is clicked, store the ip value to some variable on `window` in the `getIP` callback.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getIP(json) {
    window.ip = json.ip;
  }
</script>
```

Now on you button you can do this to display the ip:

```
<button onclick="alert(window.ip)">CLICK ME</button>
```

or simply:

```
<button onclick="alert(ip)">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: You will get an error when you click the button as it will expect a property `ip` on the parameter you pass. The button can just call `alert(ip)`.

Comment: Right. Sorry, @DaveAnderson I meant `onclick="alert(ip)"`. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Your button click event doesn't pass in the `json` parameter when it calls `getIP()`.

Instead the `onclick` event needs to call another function that will make a request for https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP.

Comment: That's not an event you have in your code sample. The `<script>` tag loads the `src` with `getIP` as the jsonp callback function. This is calling the function and passing the parameter from the response.